# How can I prevent Windows OS from entering any energy saving mode while my Java application runs?

Tags: java, windows, power-saving

I wrote a small application that is mostly listening to a message feed on a TCP connection. This application suffers from a connection drop (and so missing important messages) whenever the PC goes into energy saving mode - not sure what level, but the somewhere between screen turn off and before standby. Anyway, my question is, how would I programmatically prevent a windows host from entering a lower level while the application runs - or how can I protect the TCP connection from being dropped?

Comment: Firstly I would suspect something other than power saving could be the cause of the dropped connection. But if you're right, then there's nothing practicable you can do about it

Comment: It is the only pattern. It is also verified with Wireshark, that at the time when the computer goes into a lower state the whole communication drops. I kept my computer running during a work day and there was no hiccup for half a day. I have a break at dinner time and come back later, enter my password and its gone.

Comment: Some NIC drivers *do* have a power-saving mode. But my point remains that you can't affect that with Java. Could be doable with settings if you're lucky.

Comment: But it can be done. Apps like VLC, Chrome can stop screensaver, power state drop when videos are running. If they can do it, there must be a system call that we could do using JNI.

Comment: Yes if you resort to native code it could be possible